# How to Remove a Substring of String in a Dataframe Column?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have this simplified dataframe:

```
ID, Date
1 8/24/1995
2 8/1/1899 :00
```

How can I use the power of pandas to recognize any date in the dataframe which has extra `:00` and removes it.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

I have tried this syntax but did not help:

```
df[df["Date"].str.replace(to_replace="\s:00", value="")]
```

**The Output Should Be Like:**

```
ID, Date
1 8/24/1995
2 8/1/1899
```

Comment: Are you creating the data frame yourself? Because you could remove the extraneous `:00` prior to making the df.

Comment: I am reading a .csv file as a dataframe using `pd.read.csv()`... but I have noticed that some dates do actually have extraneous ` :00` prior to reading them as a dataframe

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to assign the trimmed column back to the original column instead of doing subsetting, and also the `str.replace` method doesn't seem to have the `to_replace` and `value` parameter. It has `pat` and `repl` parameter instead:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].str.replace("\s:00", "")

df
#   ID       Date
#0   1  8/24/1995
#1   2   8/1/1899
```

Comment: for regex based expressions don't forget to put regex = True inside replace method

Answer (score 5):

To apply this to an entire dataframe, I'd `stack` then `unstack`

```
df.stack().str.replace(r'\s:00', '').unstack()
```

[image]

#### functionalized

```
def dfreplace(df, *args, **kwargs):
    s = pd.Series(df.values.flatten())
    s = s.str.replace(*args, **kwargs)
    return pd.DataFrame(s.values.reshape(df.shape), df.index, df.columns)
```

#### Examples

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['8/24/1995', '8/1/1899 :00'], pd.Index([1, 2], name='ID'), ['Date'])

dfreplace(df, '\s:00', '')
```

[image]

---

```
rng = range(5)
df2 = pd.concat([pd.concat([df for _ in rng]) for _ in rng], axis=1)

df2
```

[image]

```
dfreplace(df2, '\s:00', '')
```

[image]